# How to start animation on hand touch event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to start animation on progress bar while user click the button and end animation when he will remove his finger from it. How can I do this? I'm not sure what to use: onmousedown/onmouseup or some handtouch events

```
 .wrapper {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute; 
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px); 
  }

 .circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 10px solid green;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
  }

  div[data-anim~=base] {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;  
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear; 
  }

 .wrapper[data-anim~=wrapper] {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.01s; 
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
 -webkit-animation-name: close-wrapper; 
 }

.circle[data-anim~=left] {
-webkit-animation-duration: 6s; 
-webkit-animation-name: left-spin;
 }

.circle[data-anim~=right] {
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
-webkit-animation-name: right-spin;
}


 <div class="wrapper" data-anim="base wrapper">
<div class="circle" data-anim="base left"></div>
<div class="circle" data-anim="base right"></div>
</div>
<button></button>
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense whatsoever. You should really improve it if you wish any useful answers ...

Answer (score 0):

The basic event of onClick and onRelease button can be achieved in the following way:

`start()` function will be called when a user clicks the button and `stop()` function will be called when the user releases the click (or removes the finger)

```html
<html>
<script>
function start(){
 changeStatus("Progress Started...");
}

function stop(){
 changeStatus("Progress Completed!");
}

function changeStatus(status){
 document.getElementById("status").innerText = status;
}
</script>
<button id="click" onmousedown="start()" onmouseup="stop()">ok</button>
<div id="status">Please click the button</div>

</html>
```